# Вывод постов по категориям(php)

Tags: php, mysqli

я хотел сделать вывод постов по категориям,но ничего не получилось.
Можете пожалуйста подсказать как это осуществить или подкинуть код.

Есть две таблицы в бд:

[таблица постов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORYlc.png)

[таблица категорий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv3QP.png)

При наведении на категорию(на сайте),уже показывается id категории(например "publichtml/catalog.php?categorie=2"),но дальше этого у меня не ушло.

Пытался искать в интернете,но там за частую WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно заменить запрос выборки из базы на подобный, если получен запрос с параметром $_GET['categorie']

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE categorie_id = {Ваш идентификатор категории}
```

Comment: ага, и получить инъекцию

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну так это пример запроса, я же не говорю его прямо в таком виде пихать. PDO никто не отменял :)

Comment: мне бы пример рабочего кода)